# Getting Helm describe-function/describe-variable’s secondary to work like helm-M-x?

Tags: helm, customize, help, documentation

When you use Helm for <kbd>M-x</kbd>, you can quickly check the documentation for an `interactive` command before calling it, it using the secondary key (usually <kbd>C-z</kbd> or <kbd>C-j</kbd>; I use the latter below). It brings up a background help buffer so you can be sure this is the command you want and you know how any arguments are used. Helm’s help line shows this: `C-j: Describe this command (keeping session)`.

It’s a fantastic quality-of-life feature. Unfortunately, it only works for *`interactive` commands*; not for non-interactive functions or variables.

When you use `describe-function` (<kbd>C-h f</kbd>) or `describe-variable` (<kbd>C-h v</kbd>), this functionality goes away, replaced by nothing. (Literally: the Helm help line reads `C-j: DoNothing (keeping session)`.)

I think I understand the motivation for this design: since you’re *in the middle of running* the interactive command to describe a function or variable, the alternate function also describing the function or variable seems redundant.

But in reality, when I’m doing Elisp coding, I frequently have used Helm to narrow down my choices of functions or variables to a manageable, but still significant number (say, eight or ten) and I’m not sure which one I want.

I’d like to press my secondary key on each to “preview” its documentation¹ before picking the one I want. But instead, my only avenue seems to be using <kbd>RET</kbd> to complete the describe command, then repeating the search with <kbd>C-h f M-p</kbd> and navigating to the next one, and so on. (If the thing I’m looking for is a buffer-local variable whose value I’m interested in, that requires even a few more keystrokes.)

If you have a number of choices and you really have no idea which one is right, it’s easy to lose track of your place (particularly after you’ve looked at a few) and repeat one you’ve already looked at—or inadvertently skip one—since you have to start at the top of the list again each time.

In Helm’s GitHub issues, there was a query about this, but the solution proposed—of simply assigning the describe function to the secondary key—results in an (interruptible) hang from infinite recursion.

So how can I achieve this?

---

¹ A “preview” sounds like I may want something different from what you get from the description—a synopsis (as you can get from interactives’ doc strings). But I just want to see the description in another buffer while keeping the Helm session open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `M-x helm-apropos` (in the `helm-elisp.el` library), which you can use to describe commands, functions, variables and faces. Pressing `C-j` shows a preview of the documentation.

Comment: Huh! I always thought of `apropos` as like, “an amalgam of `describe-*` functions”, so just assumed the Helm version would just work the same as the Helm versions of `describe-function` and `describe-variable`. I never thought to try it—so feeling dumb now, but thank you!